# How to reduce the software load by temporarily turning off viewport drawing

Tags: python, scripting

I want to use Python to bake animations with a large number of frames.
Here is an example of a Python script.

```
import bpy
import math

obj = bpy.context.object
for i in range(100000):
    obj.location = math.sin(i), 0.0, 0.0
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=i)
```

However, running this will put a lot of load on Blender and take a long time to finish.

In the case of Autodesk Maya, there is a feature to reduce the software load by temporarily turning off the viewport drawing when doing this kind of bake process.

Does Blender have a similar feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `numpy` and `foreach_set`**

IMO turning off the viewport update will have negligible effect on speeding up question code, which will simply lock blender till finished.

Both `numpy` and blenders foreach methods are designed to speed up python by eliminating long looping.

Code below

- Create a new action
- Add an x location fcurve
- Create our data in numpy frame, value pairs
- Ravel, flatten  the list `[f0, x0, f1, x1, ...]`
- Assign values to coordinate and handles of keyframe points
- Optionally bake to sampled points.
- Assign action to context object

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

n = 1000

frames = np.arange(1, n + 1)
t = np.pi * frames / 10 # sanitize for radians or use linspace directly
x = np.sin(t) # x function
action = bpy.data.actions.new("Sine")
fcurve = action.fcurves.new("location", index=0)

fcurve.keyframe_points.add(n)
for p in ("handle_left", "co", "handle_right"):
    fcurve.keyframe_points.foreach_set(
            p,
            np.array((frames, x)).T.ravel(),
            )
fcurve.convert_to_samples(0, n) # optional
# link to context object
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
ad = ob.animation_data_create()
ad.action = action
```

**Note**.

Sine is one of the built in functions available in fcurve modifiers.

[image]

and would be the optimal way to generate an endless sine wave fcurve.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using the code in your answer has sped up the sine curve generation. However, there are a few things I don't understand about using fcurve: what is the value of `index` in `action.fcurves.new("location", index=0)`?
Other questions may be asked in another post.

Comment: Index of axis _eg_ `"xyz"[0]`